# boost 1.60 with ROS Jade

Tags: catkin, boost, roscpp, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use boost 1.55 or later with ROS Jade.
How can I do it correctly ? If possible, I'd like to use boost installed locally.
As I show later, roscpp depends on boost 1.54.0 and it seems to lead to serious problem.

What I've done is like the follows.

1. Installed boost 1.60 locally (into ~/Libs/boost). 
    Now header files and .a and .so files are in ~/Libs/boost/incude and ~/Libs/boost/lib respectively
2. In CMakeLists.txt,

   > set(LIB_ROOT "~/Libs")
   > set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR ${LIB_ROOT}/boost/include)<br>
   >  set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR ${LIB_ROOT}/boost/lib)
   > find_package(Boost 1.60 REQUIRED)
   > include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})<br>
   >  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
3. Removed build and devel directories in catkin_ws and catkin_make

As a result, I have warnings as the follows:

```
link library [libboost_\*\*\*\*.so] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in: <path-to-~/Libs>/boost/lib
```

and

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_\*\*\*\*.so.1.54.0, needed by /opt/ros/jade/lib/libroscpp.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.60.0
```

Warnings make sense because I did it on purpose. 
But the warning is really scaring. I'm afraid that it was really linked correctly.

What's wrong with my way ?
Should I link boost libraries statically ?
In that case, how can I do it with catkin ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223882/boost-1.60-with-ros-jade/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2016-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't use multiple versions of boost within the same binary. Since the default installation of ROS is linked against the system version of Boost, if you want to build ROS nodes against the default ROS installation, you need to use the system installation of Boost.

If you want to use ROS with a newer version of Boost, you'll need to compile ROS from source: http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source ; and then build your nodes against that build of ROS.

As a side note, I don't think there is much testing of ROS with Boost 1.60; if there are API incompatibilities between the default version of Boost and 1.60, ROS might not build.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1